# How to create additional columns weekofyear,month and dayofweek in polars?

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I am trying to create additional columns from an existing column name in polars.
The existing column name is starttime. This column contains datetime.

| starttime | endtime | storageid | volume_id | avgiops |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-10 09:32:20 | 2022-02-10 09:34:28 | TUNYKYPG72 | 4c8d6c31 | 27 |
| 2022-02-10 10:34:10 | 2022-02-10 10:35:12 | TUNYKYPG42 | 4c8d6d31 | 34 |

From this table , I would like to create additional columns like weekofyear,dayofweek,year etc.

```
pl_df.with_column(pl.col('starttime').str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt='%Y').cast(pl.Datetime)).alias
("year")
```

But it fails as

> exceptions.ComputeError: strict conversion to dates failed, maybe set
> strict=False

In pyspark ,we can create it like below

```
df_dates = pl.select(
        [
            weekofyear("starttime").alias("week"),
            dayofweek("starttime").alias("weekday"),
            hour("starttime").alias("hour"),
            dayofmonth("starttime").alias("day"),
            to_date("starttime").alias("collectiontime"),
            starttime,endtime,storageid,volume_id,avgiops])
```

How to create additional columns weekofyear,dayofweek,month in polars?

Comment: If you provide the code for your dataframe example e.g. `df = pl.DataFrame({"starttime": [...], ... })` - it makes it much easier for us to copy/paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `.strptime(pl.Datetime)` then use the various methods [in the `.dt` namespace.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/timeseries.html)

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("starttime").str.strptime(pl.Datetime)
).with_columns([
   pl.col("starttime").dt.week().alias("week"),
   pl.col("starttime").dt.weekday().alias("weekday"),
   pl.col("starttime").dt.hour().alias("hour"),
   pl.col("starttime").dt.day().alias("day"),
])
```

```
shape: (2, 9)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────┬───────────┬─────────┬──────┬─────────┬──────┬─────┐
│ starttime           | endtime             | storageid  | volume_id | avgiops | week | weekday | hour | day │
│ ---                 | ---                 | ---        | ---       | ---     | ---  | ---     | ---  | --- │
│ datetime[μs]        | str                 | str        | str       | i64     | u32  | u32     | u32  | u32 │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪═════════╪══════╪═════════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 2022-02-10 09:32:20 | 2022-02-10 09:34:28 | TUNYKYPG72 | 4c8d6c31  | 27      | 6    | 4       | 9    | 10  │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────┼───────────┼─────────┼──────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┤
│ 2022-02-10 10:34:10 | 2022-02-10 10:35:12 | TUNYKYPG42 | 4c8d6d31  | 34      | 6    | 4       | 10   | 10  │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┴───────────┴─────────┴──────┴─────────┴──────┴─────┘
```